# FFmpeg for Android platform

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to create an android application that uses FFMpeg. For that, I downloaded the FFmpeg code(v 0.8.15) from http://www.ffmpeg.org/olddownload.html. And compiled the code as per instructions given at http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

As a result, .a files have been generated in Android/lib folder & .h files in android/include folder.

But, when I try to create .so file of my Native code what uses this prebuilt FFmpeg library (.a files), it gives undefined reference errors.

Please find my project's code structure is given below.

project path is `/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example`

At this path, I created two folders jni & prebuilt
In prebuilt folder, I kept libavfilter.a, libavcodec.a, libavformat.a, libavutil.a, libswscale.a
In jni folder, I kept one include folder that contains all .h folders (libavcodec, libavfilter, libavformat, libavutil, libswscale).

api-example.c file is also kept in jni folder that uses FFmpeg's APIs.
& one Android.mk file in jni folder.

**Android.mk:-**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libFFmpeg
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/FFMpeg/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := api-example.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../prebuilt -lavfilter -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Error:**

```
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wavpack.c:689: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wavpack.o): In function `wv_unpack_stereo':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wavpack.c:604: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wavpack.c:608: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wavpack.o):/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wavpack.c:1215: more undefined references to `av_log' follow
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wmavoice.o): In function `synth_block_fcb_acb':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:1359: undefined reference to `av_memcpy_backptr'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wmavoice.o): In function `synth_frame':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:1441: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wmavoice.o): In function `synth_superframe':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:1765: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wmavoice.o): In function `wmavoice_decode_packet':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:1919: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wmavoice.o): In function `wmavoice_decode_init':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:350: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:373: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wmavoice.o):/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wmavoice.c:397: more undefined references to `av_log' follow
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(wnv1.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/wnv1.c:81: undefined reference to `av_reverse'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(ws-snd1.o): In function `ws_snd_decode_frame':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/ws-snd1.c:70: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/ws-snd1.c:83: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/ws-snd1.c:79: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(xan.o): In function `xan_decode_frame':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/xan.c:568: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/xan.c:551: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(xan.o):/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/xan.c:515: more undefined references to `av_log' follow
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(xan.o): In function `xan_unpack':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/xan.c:178: undefined reference to `av_memcpy_backptr'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(xl.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/ffmpeg-0.8.15/libavcodec/xl.c:60: undefined reference to `av_log'
/home/guest/Neeraj_temp/FFMpeg-Example/jni/../prebuilt/libavcodec.a(xsubdec.o): In function `decode_frame'
```

I have read a lot of blogs but still not able to get the solution. Kindly provide me the solution. How do I need to structure the code that I should not get these errors & get the code compiled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded that version of FFmpeg and built it on Ubuntu Linux (but not for Android). I investigated those functions that are causing trouble for you.

It looks like you only copied some of the link errors (which is fine since the rest are probably similar). The error text shows that there are 2 symbols missing: `av_log` and `av_reverse`. Both of these are supposed to be defined in libavutil.a. Run `nm` against libavutil.a and search for `'T av_log'` and `'R av_reverse'`. Do those strings show up? If not, then certain files did not get built and archived into libavutil.a. Search through the built objects and try to verify log.o (for av_log) and mathematics.o (for av_reverse) both got built. If they don't exist, we need to figure out why the build missed them.

If those strings *do* exist in the `nm` listing, then I'm confused. That would indicate that libavutil.a is not being linked, even though I see it in your LOCAL_LDLIBS variable. The link order appears correct (avutil before libavcodec).

Comment: I checked with nm command & found av_log & av_reverse are present in libavutil.a. The Lines are:- "00000070 T av_log" & "00000200 R av_reverse". As well as I verified that log.o & matematices.o are also got built.